# Can I insert, update and delete array inside a data field in angular firebase collection?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection **users** and inside that collection is a field **list** in which I want to add list of favourite movies of a user. User can add and remove movies as per wish. I did manage to add list as array by using push().

My function

```
this.userData.list.push({
  movie_id: this.movie_detail.id,
});
let data: any = {
  id: this.userData.uid,
  password: this.userData.password,
  phone: this.userData.phone,
  role: this.userData.role,
  list: this.userData.list,
};
this.authService.updateUser(data);
```

Update function inside service:

```
updateUser(user) {
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${user.id}`);
    console.log('userDAta', noteDocRef);

    return updateDoc(noteDocRef, user);
}
```

[image: This is the result]

Right now same movie is being added multiple times. I want to prevent that. I also want to delete the movie from list if user decides to click remove button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent duplicates in an array field, you can either remove duplicates in your application code, or leave it to the database by [using the `arrayUnion` operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) when adding an item to the list:

```
const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${user.id}`);

updateDoc(noteDocRef, {
  list: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({ movie_id: this.movie_detail.id })
}
```